# np.array as default values of attributes in Python gets referenced upon by multiple instances?

Tags: python, default-arguments

I have a class with some Attribute field, which is a numpy array. The Class has the abillity to spawn new instances of the same class. Now my Problem is that all the instances
thus created seem to point at the same field-Attribute. So when the expected output of given Code is:

[0, 0]

[1, 0]

[0, 2]

it actually gives:

[1, 2]

[1, 2]

[1, 2]

and when i change an entry in a.field afterwards, the entry is changed in the field-attribute of all instances

Anybody got an idea of how to work around this or what i got wrong in understanding here?

```
import numpy as np

class A:
    def __init__(self, field=np.zeros(2)):
        self.field=field

    def setField(self, c, index):
        if index<len(self.field):
            self.field[index]=c


    def multiply(self):

        new_A=np.empty(2, dtype=object)

        for n in range(0, 2, 1):
            new_A[n]=A()
            new_A[n].setField(n+1, n)

        return new_A



a=A()

subs=a.multiply()

print a.field
print subs[0].field
print subs[1].field
```

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't put an array as a default argument, instead you should define it like this:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, field=None):
        if field is None:
            field = np.zeros(2)

        self.field=field

    def setField(self, c, index):
        if index<len(self.field):
            self.field[index]=c


    def multiply(self):

        new_A=np.empty(2, dtype=object)

        for n in range(0, 2, 1):
            new_A[n]=A()
            new_A[n].setField(n+1, n)

        return new_A
```

Check out [“Least Astonishment” in Python: The Mutable Default Argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-in-python-the-mutable-default-argument) for a detailed explanation of why you shouldn't use a list or array as a default argument.

Answer (score 1):

This is a common "gotcha" that everyone runs into when learning Python.  It has nothing to do with numpy in particular.  For example, an ordinary list would give you the same behavior.

```
>>> def f(x=[]):
...     x.append(1)
...     return x
... 
>>> f()
[1]
>>> f()
[1, 1]
>>> f()
[1, 1, 1]
```

Roughly, that code is interpreted as something like this:

```
f_default_arg_x = []
def f(x=f_default_arg_x):
    x.append(1)
    return x
```

Once you're aware that this issue exists, you can find lots of pages explaining the problem and telling you what to do about it. (For example: http://effbot.org/zone/default-values.htm)

The usual solution is to just use `None` as a placeholder for "please provide a default value".

```
def f(x=None):
    if x is None:
        x = []
    x.append(1)
    return x
```